# How secure are VPN providers?

Tags: security, vpn

Im thinking of buying a VPN service. But I Wonder how secure are these VPN services, for instance http://www.secure-vpn.com/? My Whole "internetlife" would og thru them, I dont want them to abuse my browsing history for instance, or hand in anything to their government/authorities.

Its plain simple, in todays digital age I want to be completletely invisible.

Comment: If you want to be completely invisible, stay completely away from the 'net. There is no absolute security. The net was developed by DARPA. There's a clue.

Comment: indeed. - at the absolute very least you want a company that isn't american.

Answer (score 2):

The VPN is as secure as those who run it.

Look at their policies and evaluate it for yourself. Be sure to be thorough. They may be strict regarding what you can use it for and (if they aren't outright with what they log) by seeing what they block, you can see what they monitor for.

Remember that if their servers are compromised, so is your connection.

**Tidbit:** 
The government has setup similar organizations in the past in order to catch hackers (in the instance I'm referring to it was Carders), *but that's not exactly pertinent*.

Put simply:

> Its plain simple, in todays digital age I want to be completletely invisible.

**Impossible. Trust no one.**